# Is there a way we can keep WeekWise (YYYY"W"WEEKNO) in Order

Tags: excel, sorting, powerbi

I have an excel data with Date(from Week 50, 2019 to Week 10, 2020), few columns have been added in power bi mainly Week_No, Year and Week Wise (Which is combined result of Year Column & Week_No Column) (WeekWise = 'Page 1'[Year] & "WK" &'Page 1'[Week_No])

For WeekWise Column, sorting has been done by Year.

However, when i put the Line graph, and sort it i get the graph of 2020WK10 in between 2020WK01 and 2020WK02.

Do we have a way where we can put 2020WK10 after 2020WK09?[image]

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the image the week before 2020WK10 is 2020WK1 and not 2020WK01.

Chart sorts it as Text. Hence, the error.

Rename the week numbers  in week column in the 01 formats. For that you can add ' before the leading zeros. So, the 2020WK1 will become 2020WK01 and chart will sort it correctly.

Comment: That worked thanks a lot. Used FORMAT Option in order to get result.